# The size of my LaTeX file is 39 kb but when I open it I find it empty

Tags: texmaker

I was working on Texmaker editor. I was writing an article, but suddenly, my laptop shut down. When I restarted my Windows system and I tried to open the file I find it empty. But the file size is 39 KB.

This is the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7440 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.5.28)  19 JUN 2020 06:34
entering extended mode
**"./Draft Paper.tex"
("Draft Paper.tex"
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-05-15>

LaTeX Warning: File `Draft Paper.eps' already exists on the system.
               Not generating it from this source.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fix-cm.sty"
Package: fix-cm 2015/01/14 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ts1enc.def"
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TS1 on input line 47.
)) (svjour3.cls
Document Class: svjour3 2007/05/08 v3.2 
LaTeX document class for Springer journals
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fleqn.clo"
File: fleqn.clo 2016/12/29 v1.2b Standard LaTeX option (flush left equations)
\mathindent=\dimen134
Applying: [2015/01/01] Make \[ robust on input line 50.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 51.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Make \[ robust on input line 62.
Applying: [2015/01/01] Make \] robust on input line 74.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 75.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Make \] robust on input line 83.
)
Class Springer-SVJour3 Info: extra/valid Springer sub-package (-> *.clo) 
(Springer-SVJour3)           not found in option list of \documentclass
(Springer-SVJour3)           - autoactivating "global" style.
 (svglov3.clo
File: svglov3.clo 2009/12/18 v3.2 style option for standardised journals

SVJour Class option: svglov3.clo for standardised journals
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 147.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 148.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 149.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 150.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 151.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 152.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 153.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 154.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 155.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 156.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 157.
\logodepth=\dimen135
\headerboxheight=\dimen136
\betweenumberspace=\dimen137
\aftertext=\dimen138
\headlineindent=\dimen139
\c@inst=\count167
\c@auth=\count168
\instindent=\dimen140
\authrun=\box45
\authorrunning=\toks15
\titrun=\box46
\titlerunning=\toks16
\combirun=\box47
\c@lastpage=\count169
\rubricwidth=\dimen141
\c@section=\count170
\c@subsection=\count171
\c@subsubsection=\count172
\c@paragraph=\count173
\c@subparagraph=\count174
\spthmsep=\dimen142
\c@theorem=\count175
\c@case=\count176
\c@conjecture=\count177
\c@corollary=\count178
\c@definition=\count179
\c@example=\count180
\c@exercise=\count181
\c@lemma=\count182
\c@note=\count183
\c@problem=\count184
\c@property=\count185
\c@proposition=\count186
\c@question=\count187
\c@solution=\count188
\c@remark=\count189
\c@figure=\count190
\c@table=\count191
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\figcapgap=\dimen143
\tabcapgap=\dimen144
\figgap=\dimen145
\bibindent=\dimen146
\@tempcntc=\count192
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen147
\Gin@req@width=\dimen148
)
(C:\Users\mefgo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/enumitem\enumitem.sty
Package: enumitem 2019/06/20 v3.9 Customized lists
\labelindent=\skip49
\enit@outerparindent=\dimen149
\enit@toks=\toks18
\enit@inbox=\box48
\enit@count@id=\count193
\enitdp@description=\count194
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2020/01/20 v2.17e AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip50

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks19
\ex@=\dimen150
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen151
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count195
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 227.
\uproot@=\count196
\leftroot@=\count197
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 389.
\classnum@=\count198
\DOTSCASE@=\count199
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 486.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 489.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 610.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box49
\strutbox@=\box50
\big@size=\dimen152
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 733.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 734.
\macc@depth=\count266
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count267
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count268
\dspbrk@lvl=\count269
\tag@help=\toks20
\row@=\count270
\column@=\count271
\maxfields@=\count272
\andhelp@=\toks21
\eqnshift@=\dimen153
\alignsep@=\dimen154
\tagshift@=\dimen155
\tagwidth@=\dimen156
\totwidth@=\dimen157
\lineht@=\dimen158
\@envbody=\toks22
\multlinegap=\skip51
\multlinetaggap=\skip52
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks23
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2859.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2860.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\flafter.sty"
Package: flafter 2018/11/28 v1.4d Standard LaTeX floats after reference (FMi)
Applying: [2015/01/01] float order in 2-column on input line 49.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] float order in 2-column on input line 151.
)
(C:\Users\mefgo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/multirow\multirow.sty
Package: multirow 2019/05/31 v2.5 Span multiple rows of a table
\multirow@colwidth=\skip53
\multirow@cntb=\count273
\multirow@dima=\skip54
\bigstrutjot=\dimen159
)
(C:\Users\mefgo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/booktabs\booktabs.sty
Package: booktabs 2020/01/12 v1.61803398 Publication quality tables
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen160
\lightrulewidth=\dimen161
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen162
\belowrulesep=\dimen163
\belowbottomsep=\dimen164
\aboverulesep=\dimen165
\abovetopsep=\dimen166
\cmidrulesep=\dimen167
\cmidrulekern=\dimen168
\defaultaddspace=\dimen169
\@cmidla=\count274
\@cmidlb=\count275
\@aboverulesep=\dimen170
\@belowrulesep=\dimen171
\@thisruleclass=\count276
\@lastruleclass=\count277
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen172
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\array.sty"
Package: array 2019/08/31 v2.4l Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen173
\ar@mcellbox=\box51
\extrarowheight=\dimen174
\NC@list=\toks24
\extratabsurround=\skip55
\backup@length=\skip56
\ar@cellbox=\box52
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ragged2e\ragged2e.sty"
Package: ragged2e 2019/07/28 v2.2 ragged2e Package (MS)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ms\everysel.sty"
Package: everysel 2011/10/28 v1.2 EverySelectfont Package (MS)
)
\CenteringLeftskip=\skip57
\RaggedLeftLeftskip=\skip58
\RaggedRightLeftskip=\skip59
\CenteringRightskip=\skip60
\RaggedLeftRightskip=\skip61
\RaggedRightRightskip=\skip62
\CenteringParfillskip=\skip63
\RaggedLeftParfillskip=\skip64
\RaggedRightParfillskip=\skip65
\JustifyingParfillskip=\skip66
\CenteringParindent=\skip67
\RaggedLeftParindent=\skip68
\RaggedRightParindent=\skip69
\JustifyingParindent=\skip70
)
\enitdp@tabitemize=\count278

(C:\Users\mefgo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/makecell\makecell.sty
Package: makecell 2009/08/03 V0.1e Managing of Tab Column Heads and Cells
\rotheadsize=\dimen175
\c@nlinenum=\count279
\TeXr@lab=\toks25
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\tabularx.sty"
Package: tabularx 2020/01/15 v2.11c `tabularx' package (DPC)
\TX@col@width=\dimen176
\TX@old@table=\dimen177
\TX@old@col=\dimen178
\TX@target=\dimen179
\TX@delta=\dimen180
\TX@cols=\count280
\TX@ftn=\toks26
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdfmode.def"
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-05-05 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count281
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box53
)
("Draft Paper.aux")
\openout1 = `"Draft Paper.aux"'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 98.

Unknown journal: specify \journalname{<name of your journal>} in preambel

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count282
\scratchdimen=\dimen181
\scratchbox=\box54
\nofMPsegments=\count283
\nofMParguments=\count284
\everyMPshowfont=\toks27
\MPscratchCnt=\count285
\MPscratchDim=\dimen182
\MPnumerator=\count286
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count287
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks28
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
)
ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros
LaTeX Info: Redefining \selectfont on input line 98.

SVJour3 warning: Missing \journalname

Overfull \hbox (2.78622pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 149--150
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 evolved and new wire-less pro-to-cols (e.g. Wi-Fi, WiMAX,
 []


Overfull \hbox (3.09184pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 149--150
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 the mo-bile tech-nolo-gies and their com-bi-na-tion gave birth
 []


Underfull \vbox (badness 8170) has occurred while \output is active []


Overfull \hbox (0.39734pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 151--152
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 con-cept in-cludes the fol-low-ing com-po-nents: net-work dis-
 []


Overfull \hbox (22.20305pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 151--152
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 cov-ery, au-then-ti-ca-tion, au-tho-riza-tion and ac-count-ing 
(AAA),
 []


Overfull \hbox (16.14743pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 151--152
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 mo-bil-ity man-age-ment, net-work in-ter-face se-lec-tion (NIS)
and
 []


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [1{C:/Users/mefgo/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}


]
<Pictures/Flowchart of Vertical Handover Decision.png, id=12, 2419.0375pt x 542
0.25pt>
File: Pictures/Flowchart of Vertical Handover Decision.png Graphic file (type p
ng)
<use Pictures/Flowchart of Vertical Handover Decision.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: Pictures/Flowchart of Vertical Handover Decision.png  
used on input line 167.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 222.74849pt x 499.04951pt.

Overfull \hbox (6.53615pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 176--177
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Network-related cri-te-ria: it con-tains the net-work char-
 []


Underfull \vbox (badness 1077) has occurred while \output is active []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
[][]
 []

[2]
Overfull \hbox (4.67513pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 182--184
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 very sim-ple be-cause it was mainly based on mono-criteria
 []


Overfull \hbox (0.48065pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 182--184
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 past, the han-dover de-ci-sion (net-work se-lec-tion) has been
 []


Overfull \hbox (7.61961pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 187--188
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 mal-iza-tion func-tion is used to elim-i-nate the at-tributes'
 []


Overfull \hbox (0.70282pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 188--190
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 weights. How-ever, in the rat-ing meth-ods, the weights
 []

[3 <./Pictures/Flowchart of Vertical Handover Decision.png>]
<Pictures/Classification.png, id=22, 11854.2875pt x 3121.6625pt>
File: Pictures/Classification.png Graphic file (type png)
<use Pictures/Classification.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: Pictures/Classification.png  used on input line 199.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 495.0pt x 130.32298pt.

Overfull \hbox (1.25854pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 194--204
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 op-ing, de-sign-ing and/or in-te-grat-ing dif-fer-ent ap-proach
es
 []


Overfull \hbox (9.17523pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 235--236
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 be-long-ing to the multiple-attribute de-ci-sion mak-ing meth-
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
[][]
 []

[4]
Overfull \hbox (4.36235pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 278--279
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 neg-a-tive $(\OML/cmm/m/it/10 A[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )$ ideal so-lu
-tions, where $\OML/cmm/m/it/10 A[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 = [\OML/cmm/m/it/10 d[] [] 
d[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ]$
 []


Overfull \hbox (10.7852pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 294--296
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 pear-ance of the rank re-ver-sal phe-nomenon in AHP method
 []

[5 <./Pictures/Classification.png>]
Overfull \hbox (1.86952pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 315--316
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 The best Al-ter-na-tive is that hav-ing the high-est score,
 []


Overfull \hbox (14.14522pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 320--321
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 WPM also called MEW (mul-ti-plica-tive ex-po-nen-tial weight-
 []


Overfull \hbox (8.78627pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 328--329
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 to com-pare the per-for-mance of the three fol-low-ing MADM
 []


Overfull \hbox (5.9252pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 328--329
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 bust-ness. Fi-nally, they spec-i-fied the best rank-ing method.

 []


Overfull \hbox (15.48071pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 328--329
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 por-tance, the work in [22]did not eval-u-ate the user's/servic
e
 []


Overfull \hbox (97.65625pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 341--342
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 the lower bound is spec-i-fied as fol-lows: $\OML/cmm/m/it/10 L
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 = \OML/cmm/m/it/10 min\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 A[]\
OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 j\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ; A[]\OT1/c
mr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 j\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ) [] \OML/cmm/m/it/10 A[]\OT1/cmr/
m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 j\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ; j \OT1/cmr/m/n/10
 =
 []


Overfull \hbox (5.53629pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 364--365
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Finally, rank-ing the al-ter-na-tive (net-works) and choos-
 []


Overfull \hbox (3.45291pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 376--377
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 with many prob-lems. In micro-economics, the term `Util-
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
[][]
 []

[6]
Overfull \hbox (1.25854pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 383--384
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 util-ity func-tion of at-tributes dif-fers from an at-tribute
 []

LaTeX Font Info:    Calculating math sizes for size <8.5> on input line 389.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMX/cmex/m/n' in size <8.5> not available
(Font)              size <8> substituted on input line 389.


Overfull \hbox (10.32195pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 389--409
[][] 
 []


Overfull \hbox (11.14632pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 419--420
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ing Sum and Eu-clid-ian nor-mal-iza-tions AHP for weight-
 []


Overfull \hbox (1.56299pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 419--420
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ing) with MADM com-bi-na-tions (em-ploy-ing also Sum
 []


Overfull \hbox (3.42503pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 427--429
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 move the rank re-ver-sal phe-nomenon. Re-searchers,
 []


Overfull \hbox (7.95285pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 427--429
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 showed that the rank re-ver-sal is com-pletely voided,
 []


Overfull \hbox (2.06401pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 429--430
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 im-prove the user/application re-quire-ment and/or
 []


Overfull \hbox (0.39735pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 429--430
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 im-prove the rank-ing qual-ity. In [29], au-thors used
 []


Overfull \hbox (0.5239pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 456--457
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Type
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 456--457
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 of
 []


Overfull \hbox (0.5239pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 458--459
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Type
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 458--459
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 of
 []


Overfull \hbox (5.9206pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 458--459
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Learn-
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 460--461
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Method of
 []


Overfull \hbox (3.51508pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 464--465
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Ref 
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 481--482
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Gradient
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 7722) in paragraph at lines 481--482
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 de-scent back-
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 483--484
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 One hid-den
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 493--494
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Background
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 506--508
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 packet loss
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 513--514
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Predict the
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 513--514
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 char-ac-ter-is-tics
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 513--514
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 of the best
 []


Overfull \hbox (4.14668pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 520--521
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 [30] 
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 526--527
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Levenberg{
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 526--527
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Mar-quardt
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 526--527
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 back-prop-a-ga-
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 528--529
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Two hid-den
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 528--529
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 lay-ers (10
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 6220) in paragraph at lines 528--529
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 nodes and 5
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 545--546
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Access Point
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 545--546
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Can-di-date
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 547--548
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Evaluate the
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 549--550
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 the adap-tive
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 549--550
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 fuzzy logic
 []


Overfull \hbox (4.14668pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 553--554
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 [31]| 
 []


Overfull \vbox (2.26738pt too high) detected at line 558
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 560--561
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Back-
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 562--563
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Two hid-den
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 569--570
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 in the time
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 571--572
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Predict the
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 571--572
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 num-ber of
 []


Overfull \hbox (4.14668pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 578--579
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 [32] 
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 589--590
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Back-
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 591--592
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 One hid-den
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 601--602
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Monetary
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 606--607
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Good, Fair,
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 608--609
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Classify the
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 6792) in paragraph at lines 610--611
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Generated by
 []


Overfull \hbox (4.14668pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 615--616
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 [33] 
 []


Overfull \hbox (32.79057pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 451--620
 [][] 
 []


Overfull \hbox (102.94852pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 707--707
[]|[]| 
 []


Overfull \hbox (9.316pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 707--707
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Characteristics
 []


Overfull \hbox (25.30449pt too wide) in alignment at lines 707--707
[][][][][][] 
 []


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [7]
("Draft Paper.bbl"
Overfull \vbox (128.1598pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
[][]
 []

[8]
Underfull \hbox (badness 1831) in paragraph at lines 180--183
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8.5 Wire-less per-sonal com-mu-ni-ca-tions \OT1/cmr/bx/n/8.5 71\OT
1/cmr/m/n/8.5 (4), 2399--2415
 []

) [9] ("Draft Paper.aux")

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 0.5pt have occurred.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3080 strings out of 480795
 45713 string characters out of 2905357
 319901 words of memory out of 3000000
 19050 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 542563 words of font info for 59 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 30i,16n,38p,1404b,410s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
 <C:\Users\mefgo\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/dpi637\
tcrm0800.pk><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbsy10
.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><C:
/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Program
 Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx8.pfb><C:/Program Files/Mi
KTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9
/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cmextra/cmex7.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fon
ts/type1/public/amsfonts/cmextra/cmex8.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/t
ype1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/pub
lic/amsfonts/cm/cmmi5.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfo
nts/cm/cmmi7.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cm
mi8.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><
C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr5.pfb><C:/Program
 Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiK
TeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type
1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy5.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/
amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/
cm/cmsy8.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10
.pfb>
Output written on "Draft Paper.pdf" (9 pages, 1455653 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 122 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 11 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: If your editor was trying to write on your `.tex` file, there is a real possibility that the file is damaged. I hope for you that you have recent a backup of the file. You'll probably want to contact data recovery experts if you need the file back. A LaTeX forum is not going to be of  much help, I'm afraid.

Comment: TeXmaker creates backup files. Have a look into your documents directory for files like `<name>.tex.bak`

Comment: If I remember correctly, time ago I successfully  recovered one file damaged in this way  with testdisk in Linux.   If you have a hexadecimal  viewer, probably you will see some of the contents. But if you do not have any backup, take care of not overwrite the file (i.e, do not edit the file!)

Comment: @moewe when I open it as a .tex file, I find the file empty.

Comment: @user187802 I didn't find any tex.bak file

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that, I recover the files by using an option exist in windows 10. I restore my tex file.

Comment: Good that you have recovered your file. Maybe you can add some more details to your answer, so other people that have the same problem can find the solution more easily? You can add information by pressing the small `edit` button below your answer.